# unable to start file from script using remmina snap

Tags: kubuntu, kde, snap, remmina

I have remmina installed through snap, all persmissions required for remmine in snap (including home dir) are set correctly.

Starting remmina through kde launcher works
starting remmina in Konsole with:

```bash
remmina --connect=/home/user/Documents/location_of_file/file.remmina
```

works
placing the line above in a script, and launching it from Konsole also works.

But lauching the script through a custom keyboard shortcut in KDE fails.
apparmor denies access to remmina to the file.

I've been succesfully using this method of launching since the first installation of Kubuntu 22.04

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix this?